# bind Spring HandlerInterceptor only to one controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring 3.0.2.RELEASE. I'm having 2 Controllers in package com.myCompany. The Controllers are activated via Component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCompany" />
```

then I'm having a interceptor bind to the 2 controllers via

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
   <property name="interceptors">
     <list>
       <ref bean="myInterceptor"/>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

How can i bind the interceptor to only one specific Controller or to only certain methods inside a Controller?
Background: I want to inspect the URL that it contains certain parameters

[Docu Link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html)

Comment: Check also [this solution](http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/athandlerinterceptor-for-spring-mvc/) with use of custom annotation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you inject interceptors into a `HandlerMapping` bean, those interceptors apply to every handler mapped by that `HandlerMapping`. That was fine in the pre-annotation days, since you'd just have configure multiple `HandlerMapping` beans. However, with annotations, we tend to have a single `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` that maps everything, so this model doesn't work.

The solution is to use `<mvc:interceptors>`, where you explicitly map paths to interceptor beans. See the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors), and this example:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/secure/*"/>
        <bean class="org.example.SecurityInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Thanks. But i don't get it. Can I add the snippet into the File containing "<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCompany" /> ? Then I get "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:interceptors'."
I added xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

Comment: @Martin: See the fixed link to the docs. You need add the `schemaLocation` in addition to the namespace.

Comment: Thanks skaffman. It works! I've overseen the link.. What Spring sources do you recommend for getting more involved?

Comment: @Martin: Hard to say. I've been using Spring since 1.2.8, so I've kind of grown with it. I still think the reference manual is excellent, though.

Comment: So, can't I map an interceptor to some controller? Just mapping by path is available?

Comment: i think you should change the mapping tag to mvc:mapping. ` <mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/secure/*" />
   <bean class="org.example.SecurityInterceptor" />
  </mvc:interceptor>
 </mvc:interceptors>`