# Ajax request omitted by interceptors

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I need to call my own intercpetor's methods when ajax requests (`Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`) are received.

I added it to `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`. My interceptor extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and implements `ServletContextAware`, `InitializingBean`. How could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must register your interceptor manually:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.MyCustomInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

See also:

- [bind Spring HandlerInterceptor only to one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469489)
- [@HandlerInterceptor for Spring MVC](http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/athandlerinterceptor-for-spring-mvc/)

Comment: I have registered interceptor using <mvc:interceptors/>. It doesn't work only with ajax requests.

Comment: You mean that if you enter the same URL with browser address bar or using `wget`/`curl` it works?