# Wiring Custom HandlerInterceptor for Urls in Plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.3

I'm wanting to convert my filters to a handlerInterceptor in my plugin but am not quite sure how to go about it. It looks like I am supposed to use 'doWithSpring' and map a handler interceptor but I'm not seeing where I map the url's.

To save some discussion, I know filters do this in grails. I just want to convert this code to Java in my plugin and use a HandlerInterceptor to decrease overhead on these calls.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think I may have solved it. You have to extend the HandlerInterceptor and register the bean...

```
mvc.'interceptors'() {
    mvc.'mapping'('path': '/your/uri/**') {
        bean('class': 'CustomInterceptor')
    }
}
```

Here's a link to what I'm talking about ([bind Spring HandlerInterceptor only to one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469489/bind-spring-handlerinterceptor-only-to-one-controller))

Going to try this out and test it...

Answer (score 0):

In Grails all handler interceptors are registered with the `filterInterceptor` bean which is a `CompositeInterceptor`. To add new handler interceptors to this bean use the `addHandler` method.

The source code for the [CompositeInterceptor](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-filters/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/filters/CompositeInterceptor.java) should give you a better idea of how this is done. Off the top of my head it may look something like this:

```
def doWithSpring = {
  filterInterceptor.addHandler(MyCustomHandlerClass)
}
```

As far as what URLs your handlers respond to, well, that's up to your implementation inside the handler.

Comment: trying to avoid use of the filter as I can just use the filter directly in the plugin. want to use underlying spring handlerInterceptors directly to avoid a bit of runaround in the application. This may be outside the app context but I can always grab the context should I need it; more worried about grabbing request/response.

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression this is the actual handler interceptors for the entire spring application with full access to the request/response.

Comment: we are talking the same thing... the handlerInterceptor. I don't want a filter as I can just use a filter directly. Why would I create one indirectly when I can go to the source? Thats what I am talking about. I want to create Java classes that make use of a handlerInterceptor in a grails plugin

Comment: Then create those java classes and register them as I have outlined there. Nothing stopping you from doing that inside your plugin.

Comment: Your advice is to add as a filterInterceptor which I am trying to avoid as filters are merely handlerInterceptors from my understanding and it would be a 'shortcut' and provide faster processing for a single interpreted endpoint to go directly through a handlerInterceptor if you can.

Comment: So, are you looking to register a ServletFilter or a HandlerInterceptor? Don't be confused by the name filterInterceptor, it's actually a collection of HandlerInterceptors, of which the Grails Filters do become. Sorry for not understanding exactly what you are looking for here, but it's likely the terminology that has me confused.

Comment: No problem. Yeah this is why I say handlerInterceptor because thats the name of the class that you extend. I think its my fault for confusing you with the code example below... let me fix real quick :)