# how to apply post method to all request mappings in spring

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc

How i can access to request POST data from different url-s to one controller method, for example I have `/countries` & `/countries/{id}` URL, It works very good with first one, because my code is

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/{id}", "/{id}/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getCountry(@PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) int id,ModelMap model) {

    }

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String deleteCountry(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {  

    }
```

And when I try to request POST data from second url I'm getting

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported
```

Which is expectable because I haven't POST method with this mapping, but if I will be made one method for one mapping my code will be too ugly ant terrible, what solution I can use?

Comment: I found a solution via regexp in url, is it only one possible way?

Comment: "Ugly and terrible"--you have to provide *an implementation* somehow, right? How does this make your code terrible?

Answer (score 3):

Hum why not add the "array" of value to your second method as well ?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/{id}"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteCountry(ModelMap model,
                            HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Btw using POST verb to call an action that looks like it will delete the resource seems wrong, it should be a DELETE verb used

---

EDIT
But in reality, you should be creating 2 methods, as both those method are not supposed to do the same thing.

`POST` `/countries` should be creating country resources

`POST` `/countries/{id}` should be doing something else.

For an update prefer `PUT` `/countries/{id}`

And for a delete, prefer `DELETE` `/countries/{id}`

Comment: In fact a value of request mapping can be "/**" i not found any regexp in url in google. Delete and put methods? Yes, It's good, unfortunatly my client wants something in RPC style without these methods.

Comment: But I do not understand how a `POST` on `/countries` and a `POST` on a `/countries/{id}` should end up in the same method, doing the same thing. One has a unique resource identifier, not the other ?

Comment: Well, what if we want to place delete button in the countries view layer and in the single country view, i thought It's offer task for web dev, nothing especial.

Comment: So you want to delete one or delete all right ? Imo binding 2 different path to one entry point to then split behavior based on null check, is not the most readable way to do it. But it'll work sure ...

Comment: No, for example, I want to delete one country in country list (/countries) and same country in It full describe view (extand view) /country/{id}.

Comment: In both those case the APi path you would call would be  /country/{id}. Because you would need to identify which country to delete, with the path param id.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to have separate handler interceptors for different controllers.
Refer this link for details.

[bind Spring HandlerInterceptor only to one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469489/bind-spring-handlerinterceptor-only-to-one-controller)

But I feel, it may be good you can create a common method to share business logic for this.
As Interceptor comes with proxy class for your controller which can be avoided unless you have complex logic.